# Symfony2 entities best practice

Tags: entity-framework, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, entity

I would like to know what's the best practice to do this :

I have :
An entity **Item**,
an entity **User**,
and an entity **Favourite** (Favourite is composed of one User and one Item, and I have a unique constraint on those two fields)

I would like to list 40 items by page and display for each item if it is in the current user's favourite or not. What's the best way? I already thought about some solutions.

**Solution 1**
Add an integer property named favourite to my Item entity. Get all Item's id (IDS) of the current page, and get all the Favourite with the operator IN (IDS). With a loop on Favourite I will set the Item property to 1 for "favoured", and I will let the other to null for "unfavoured". Disadvantage, I couldn't use Favourite's information by just using an integer property.

**Solution 2**
Add an array collection property named favourites to my Item entity, which will be on relation OneToMany with Favourite entity. Thus when I will list the Items, I could rewrite the jointure (left join) with the createQueryBuilder method between Item and Favourite, to get only one or any Favourite by Item, this by specifying the current user favourite. Disadvantage, I rewrite the current favourite item list, so I will not get all favourites, but only the current user's favourite.

I don't know what's the best practice to do this, I wouldn't have to make a query for each item, it's too weight... if you have a better solution, a comment about my different solutions, or a bundle with a sample, I would appreciate that :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need for an extra bundle for this, and I doubt there even exists one. This is a really simple task that is tackled fairly easily in most social networks where someone can post (in your case 'item') users can like a post (in your case'favorite').

The easy common way to do this by creating a favorites entity (table) which has two important columns each with a many-to-one mapping. One to the users table and one to the items table, each of which respectively have a one-to-many mapping. i.e many users can favorite one item, many items can be favored or "favorited" by one user. This new entity contains all this data and don't worry about query speed, in my experince doctrine automatically creates indexes for mapped columns on related tables.